# Adapting design to Grails

Tags: grails, domain-model

I've finished a php/mysql CMS project, and since grails is the main subject for one of my classes, I figured why not play around with it some more and adapt the CMS to a grails app.

I'm currently modeling the domain, which consist of 4 classes: `User`, `Labs`, `Files` and `Support`.  The `User` is the main domain of the app and has many `Labs`.  Each `Labs` object has many `Files` and a single `Support`.

The goal of `Support` is to reference all the `Users` that are attached to a particular lab.  Each lab has a lead, staff of 0 to many and a faculty advisor.  My problem is how do I model this in Grails?  I'm currently declaring a `User lead` and `User faculty` in the class, but am not sure how to manage 0 to many support staff.

If I do a `static hasMany [user:User]`, this means that any `User` attached to the `Support` will  be added without a distinguishing role.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just calling the relationship staff.

```
class Support{
   static hasMany = [ staff : User ] 
   User lead
   User facultyAdvisor
}
```

In your code then, you will call:

```
def support = new Support()
support.addToStaff( user1 )
```

which makes sense to me.

Your hasMany can be called anything. You can even have a relationship like

```
class Support{
    static hasMany = [ staff:User, leads: User, facultyAdvisors: User ]
}
```

and this will allow you to distinguish the users by role.